# Bootstrap select - lazy creation of option elements?

Tags: bootstrap-selectpicker

This may be trivial.

I have a large array and want the select to create the option elements only as necessary - me creating them all up front is too slow. I saw a few hints that this might be possible with bootstrap-select as it is but I haven't seen that it is fully possible....

Comment: Necessary as in viewport or some other logics?

Comment: more than 10,000 of them takes > 1 sec to populate the dom with... and I was thinking the virtual scroll only applies after the dom is populated.  I just got some pointers on this on their github page - https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2081 - about to go see how to have the livesearch work without having the dom elements in there yet

Comment: btw - I had forgotten about jqueryui's autocomplete - it definitely does the lazy loading thing because you pass it an array of items - https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/